# How To Set The Lengths So It Is Equal To Expected Number

Tags: geometry

[image]

I want to reduces the lengths of line `a` and `b` (but keep them equals) so the length from x to y is an expected number, in this case it will be `4`.

`- assume that x is the most bottom of line b, and y is the most top of line c`.

`- The top of line a and c should always in one straight horizontal line, because line c is just to measure the straight vertical length of line a.`

Can that be done? If it can, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

$a = b$

$c = \frac{a}{\sqrt2}$

So the distance from $x$ to $y$ is $b + c$

or $a + \frac{a}{\sqrt2} = 1.7071a$

Say you wanted to reduce the height from $x$ to $y$ from $10$ to $8$.

$1.7071a = 10$

so $a = \frac{10}{1.7071} = 5.8579 = b$

$1.7071a = 8$

so $a = \frac{8}{1.7071} = 4.6863 = b$

Comment: That give me an idea even I don't understand that codes.

Answer (score 0):

This has actually infinite solutions.One of the solutions is at x=$\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Let the angle between the line 'a' and line 'c' be $\theta$.
According to given condition a=b and b+c=4.

But c=acos$\theta$

So b+acos$\theta$=4

b+bcos$\theta$=4

b(1+cos$\theta$)=4

b=$\frac{4}{1+cos\theta}$

But the trivial maximum and minimum of b is 4 and 0 respectively.

So,

0< b<4(Equal to is not considered as at those points a tends to $\infty$ or 0 which is meaningless).

0<$\frac{4}{1+cos\theta}$<4

Since $\frac{4}{1+cos\theta}$ is always positive the inequality reduces to,

$\frac{4}{1+cos\theta}$<4

${1+cos\theta}$>1

$cos\theta$>0

$\theta$<$\frac{\pi}{2}$

So there are infinite values of theta for which this is true.

You can check it for $\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{3}$,$\frac{\pi}{6}$ so on.